# How to print child, father, mother from these two tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, pivot

Below are the tables:

**relation** table

| cid | pid |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 202 |
| 566 | 322 |
| 875 | 345 |

**people** table

| id | name | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Riya | F |
| 566 | Aman | M |
| 202 | Rakesh | M |
| 875 | lucky | M |
| 202 | Reena | F |
| 322 | Raina | F |
| 345 | Rohit | M |
| 322 | Mohit | M |
| 345 | Meena | F |

**output**

| Child | Mother | Father |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Riya | Reena | Rakesh |
| Aman | Raina | Mohit |
| Lucky | Rohit | Meena |

I tried this:

```
SELECT     mother,
           father
FROM      (
                      SELECT     id,
                                 name,
                                 sum(
                                 CASE
                                            WHEN gender = 'F' THEN 1
                                            ELSE 0) AS mother,
                                 sum (
                                 CASE
                                            WHEN gender = 'M' THEN 1
                                            ELSE 0) AS father
                      FROM       people
                      INNER JOIN relation
                      ON         people. id = relation.p_id
                      GROUP BY   id,
                                 name) t1
INNER JOIN relation
ON         relation.p_id = t1.id
```

Please let me know the query, for how to fetch this output. this above query does not work, I am not able to figure how to output child also.

Comment: You need to `JOIN` **relationship** with **people** twice (using different aliases).

Comment: To add to the previous comment, that is commonly called a [self join](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-self-join/).

Answer (score 6):

You must join `relation` to 2 copies of `people`.
The 1st copy will return the child's name and the 2nd copy will return the names of the parents.
Then group by child and use conditional aggregation to get the names of the parents in one row:

```
SELECT c.name Child, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.gender = 'F' THEN p.name END) Mother, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN p.gender = 'M' THEN p.name END) Father
FROM relation r
INNER JOIN people c ON c.id = r.cid
INNER JOIN people p ON p.id = r.pid
GROUP BY r.cid, c.name;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5cb9be3cf08b393788781f4bc73f26a4).

Comment: why we are using MAX() in this problem

Answer (score 2):

You can join twice and then `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT c.name AS child,
         p.name AS parent,
         p.gender
  FROM   relations r
         INNER JOIN people c
         ON r.cid = c.id
         INNER JOIN people p
        ON r.pid = p.id
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(parent) FOR gender IN (
    'M' AS father,
    'F' AS mother
  )
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE people (id, name, gender) AS
SELECT 101, 'Riya',   'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 566, 'Aman',   'M' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 202, 'Rakesh', 'M' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 875, 'lucky',  'M' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 202, 'Reena',  'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 322, 'Raina',  'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 345, 'Rohit',  'M' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 322, 'Mohit',  'M' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 345, 'Meena',  'F' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE relations (cid, pid) AS
SELECT 101, 202 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 566, 322 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 875, 345 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CHILD | FATHER | MOTHER |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Riya | Rakesh | Reena |
> | Aman | Mohit | Raina |
> | lucky | Rohit | Meena |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8869d876e9a60c400aaf28b8efeaa1eb)*

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
with cte as
(
 select name as child, r.pid as pid 
   from people p
   join relation r
     on p.id=r.cid
)
select ee.child as child, 
       (select name from people PM where id=ee.pid and PM.gender='F') as Mother,
       (select name from people PP where id=ee.pid and PP.gender='M') as Father 
  from cte ee
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query -

```
SELECT P.name Child, p2.name mother, p3.name father
  FROM relation R
  JOIN people P ON R.cid = P.id
  JOIN people P2 ON R.pid = P.id
                AND P.gender = 'F'
  JOIN people P3 ON R.pid = P.id
                AND P.gender = 'M'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT P1.NAME AS CHILD,(SELECT NAME FROM PEOPLE PM WHERE ID=T.PID AND PM.GENDER='F') AS MOTHER,
       (SELECT NAME FROM PEOPLE PP WHERE ID=T.PID AND PP.GENDER='M') AS FATHER FROM 
(SELECT R.CID,NAME,R.PID,P.GENDER FROM PEOPLE P,RELATIONS R
WHERE P.ID=R.PID) T,PEOPLE P1
WHERE T.CID=P1.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from
(select * from
(select  p.firstname as child, (select p1.firstname from persons p1 where r.p_id=p1.id and p1.gender='M') as father
from persons p inner join relations r on
p.id=r.id
) t

where t.father is not null
) as table1
inner join

(select * from
(select  p.firstname as child, (select p1.firstname from persons p1 where r.p_id=p1.id and p1.gender='F') as mother
from persons p inner join relations r on
p.id=r.id
) t

where t.mother is not null ) as table2

on table1.child=table2.child

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as a short explanation of your solution. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT l.cid       AS id,
           r.NAME      AS Child,
           mother.NAME AS Mother,
           father.NAME AS Father
    FROM   testdb.dbo.people r
           JOIN testdb.dbo.relation l
             ON l.cid = r.id
           JOIN (SELECT l.cid AS id,
                        r.NAME
                 FROM   testdb.dbo.people r
                        JOIN testdb.dbo.relation l
                          ON l.pid = r.id
                             AND gender = 'F') AS mother
             ON l.cid = mother.id
           JOIN (SELECT l.cid AS id,
                        r.NAME
                 FROM   testdb.dbo.people r
                        JOIN testdb.dbo.relation l
                          ON l.pid = r.id
                             AND gender = 'M') AS father
             ON l.cid = father.id
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72447283/edit) to add further details, such as a short explanation of your solution. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Query that prints the names of a child and his parents in individual columns respectively in order of the name of the child.

```
SELECT c.name as child, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.gender = 'F' THEN p.name END) AS mother,
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.gender = 'M' THEN p.name END) AS father
FROM relations r
INNER JOIN public."People" c on c.id = r.cid
INNER JOIN public."People" p on p.id = r.pid
GROUP BY r.cid, c.name ORDER BY c.name;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.name as child,c.name as father,d.name as mother from   relation a join people b on a.cid=b.id 
join people c  on  a.pid=c.id 
join people d on  a.pid=d.id where c.gender='m' and d.gender='f'
```

Comment: Please add explanations.